# Insert <div> under the header on a specific category page

Tags: php, wordpress

In my Wordpress website i made this code in header.php that write html under the header only if you are on a specific post (product) page,

```
<?php
    $post = get_post();
        if ( $post->ID == 'postid' ){
            echo '<div>
                <p>'text'
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';
}
?>
```

I would like to make the same thing in a specific category page doing something like this

```
<?php
$postcat = get_the_category();
    if ( $postcat->ID == 'categoryid'){{
        echo '<div>
            <p>'text'
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';
}
?>
```

But it doesn't work, i also tried different method like

```
<?php if (is_category('categoryname')) : ?>
   <div></div>
?php endif;?>
```

How can i do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `is_product_category`. check the below code.

```
<?php
    if ( is_product_category( 'your-category-slug' ) ){
                echo '<div>
                    <p>'text'</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';
    }
?>
```

USEFUL LINKE

- [conditional-tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/)

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfect! I wasn't considering woocommerce tags.

Comment: Welcome... glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

If post = specific ID

```
<?php
$post = get_post();
if ( $post->ID === 'postid' ){
    echo "<div>";
    echo $post->post_content;
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Is post has category "supercat"

```
<?php
$post = get_post();
if ( has_category('supercat', $post->ID)){
    echo "<div>";
    echo $post->post_content;
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

For products , check Bhautik's answer